# Schema design for tracking the gaz prices in MongoDB

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema, update, nosql

I would like to build an app that give the ability to

- search for the cheapest gaz price around
- Display the gaz price trend whether it's up or down.(similar to the stock price)

The data source are extracted from an OpenData API and updated every 10 minutes. As I want to keep track of the gaz prices, I came up with 2 collections: One for the gaz station information and the second for the gaz price information.

In a nutshell, here is the gaz station collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6315f810de86e476ce0519a1"
  },
  "station_id": 78310001,
  "city": "Coignières",
  "station_type": "R",
  "address": "RN10",
  "zipcode": "78310",
  "location_GeoDecimal": [
    48.74514,
    1.92182
  ],
  "services": [
    "DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)"
  ],
  "scraping_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1662384143352"
    }
  }
}
```

and the gaz prices collection

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6315f810de86e476ce04f2b4"
  },
  "station_id": 78310001,
  "price_detail": [
    {
      "fuel_id": 1,
      "fuel_name": "Gazole",
      "fuel_cost": 1.863
    },
    {
      "fuel_id": 2,
      "fuel_name": "SP95",
      "fuel_cost": 2.052
    },
    {
      "fuel_id": 4,
      "fuel_name": "GPLc",
      "fuel_cost": 0.78
    },
    {
      "fuel_id": 6,
      "fuel_name": "SP98",
      "fuel_cost": 2.074
    }
  ]
}
```

knowing there are more than 10.0k documents and each day I'll add the new gaz price, this type of schema design and work flow might lead to the `price_detail` array growing indefinitely which means that it will most likely encounter issues in future if the application runs long enough due to the fact that it may hit the BSON document size limit.

What would be your approach on this? How would you design such schema?

Comment: "*is mongoDB a good fit ?*' - Unless you expect the schema to change shape frequently, I don't see why this couldn't be done in any traditional relational database management system. You definitely wouldn't be hitting any BSON limitations there (since they don't use BSON).

Comment: I opted for MongoDB for learning purposes. I just wanted to know if this use case was possible with MongoDB. But I agree, it would have been easier if I had used a traditional relational database management system.

Comment: Gotcha, best of luck!